# EntityFramework updating model from database results in mapping file not created

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am having some trouble adding a table to my data entity model.

EntityFramework 6.1.3 installed

VS Enterprise 2017 15.9.3

Repro steps:

- I open my Model.edmx
- Right click > Update Model From Database
- Add Table > select my table > Finish

And when I go into Model.Context.cs I see this line for my newly added table:

```
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MyTable_Mapping());
```

but the MyTable_Mapping is underlined and complains the file is missing.

And inside Model.Mapping.cs reads

```
ErrorGeneratingOutput
```

My table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
  [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [AccountUserId] [int] NOT NULL,
  [MFAUserId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
  [LastAuthDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
  [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
  [StatusId] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
  [Id] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```